# node v8 deoptimizing because of weak objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I am trying to make a little router. It manages to hit 70k request per second, but after around a minute, it drops down to 50k. I then ran the same program, but with the `--trace-deopt` flag and saw that it was deoptimizing with the reason of weak objects.

```
[marking dependent code 0x004bda6d5a81 (opt #114) for deoptimization, reason: weak objects]
[marking dependent code 0x004bda6c2001 (opt #95) for deoptimization, reason: weak objects]
[marking dependent code 0x004bda5e3001 (opt #50) for deoptimization, reason: weak objects]
[marking dependent code 0x004bda5dcac1 (opt #40) for deoptimization, reason: weak objects]
...
```

I am not sure why it is and will be happy if someone helps me :)

Here is the code of the program.

```js
var http = require("http");

var map = {
  GET: {
    "/test": [],
  },
};

map.GET["/test"].push((req, res) => {
  res.end("some route");
});

function handle(req, res) {
  var handlers = map[req.method][req.url];
  var pointer = 0;
  req.next = function () {
    handlers[++pointer](req, res);
  };
  handlers[pointer](req, res);
}

var app = http.createServer(handle);
app.listen(8080);
```

Edit:

I did the same experiment with less code and still got the same results

```js
var http = require("http");

function handle(req, res) {
  switch (req.url) {
    case "/hello": {
      res.end("world");
      break;
    }
  }
}

var app = http.createServer(handle);
app.listen(8080);
```

So, this weak objects thing is not in my control, I think. I am still interested to know if there is a way to fix it. Because I know some routing frameworks that are not affected by it.

Thank you

Comment: I think that at least the first step of an explanation is here:  [Temporary objects in Chrome](https://benediktmeurer.de/2016/10/11/the-case-of-temporary-objects-in-chrome/).

Comment: I don't really get it. But is there an obvious solution to fix it?

Comment: add `--trace-opt` flag too, you're just seeing what was deoptimised.. btw its not a bug, the fix is not to look ;p and simply remove the flag

Comment: FYI, a possible theory is that your slowdown could also just be the consequences of steady state garbage collecting getting done.  Initially, while the server is busy, it doesn't run the GC very much, then as memory use rises, perhaps it decides it needs to run GC more often and thus you see some slowdown due to that.

Comment: @jfriend00: the issue described in the link in your first comment was supposedly fixed in 2018, so unless stryz_ is using a very old Node version, there must be something else going on here (I don't know what that might be, though).

Comment: @jmrk, I am using the latest version of node.